# Простой вопрос по распределению данных в базе

Tags: php, mysql

На сайте есть некое подобие системы "лобби". В виде чего лучше хранить данные об этих лобби и того, что в них происходит ? 
Лучше чтобы каждое лобби было отдельной таблицей и происходящее вносилось в эту самую отдельную таблицу ? 
Или лучше создать две таблицы, "лобби" и "записи" и наладить связи и соответствия ?

Comment: Две таблицы. Паттерн с таблицей под каждую сущность никогда не бывает оправданным, особенно, если там повторяющаяся структура. Индексы растут с логарифмической сложностью, поэтому большой разницы, сколько в таблице данных, на самом деле нет до тех пор, пока индексы используются.

Comment: @Etki А если существует условие, что созданное лобби, после выполнения своей функции удаляется ? И большое количество лобби постоянно создаются и  удаляются каждые 5-10 минут. Это никак не повлияет на ваш ответ ?

Comment: Нет, это по-прежнему нормальное функционирование для БД. Более того, в случае времени жизни таблицы в пять-десять минут вы рискуете рано или поздно столкнуться с проблемой гейзенбагов: в лобби возникла какая-то ошибка, а проанализировать ее невозможно из-за отсуствия каких-либо следов в БД. Более того, лобби не обязательно удалять, можно просто добавить поле `is_closed` как раз для полседующего хранения и аналитики. Удалить всегда успеется )